# Cannot create a Permission Set related to an Idea via Console or Anonymous

Tags: permissions, apex

I am trying to create a permission set in my code but I'm getting some issues when I tried to assign an Idea, Product2 or Pricebook. With some other objects like custom or other Standards, I'm able to do it without any issue.

What is it wrong?

```
PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
ps.Name='TestPermissionSet';
ps.label='TestPermissionSet';
insert ps;

//insert Object permission for Idea
ObjectPermissions op = new ObjectPermissions();
op.parentId = ps.Id;
op.SobjectType = 'Idea';
op.PermissionsCreate = true;
op.PermissionsRead = true;
insert op;
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
System.DMLException: Insert failed. 
First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, 
The following permission isn't allowed: Read All Idea: []
```

Thanks

Comment: Odd. I got the same error when trying from anonymous Apex against Product2 but was able to create the ObjectPermissions via the UI with /0PS700000000001/e?s=EntityPermissions&o=Product2. Can you create them via the GUI for Ideas?

Comment: Yes, if I try via UI, there is no issue and I'm able to create whatever I need. I only get the error if I do it via Console or anonymous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agustina, thank you for posting. I am on the Admin team at salesforce.com and have been able to reproduce this particular issue. You should be able to perform the action you are attempting, but our API validation logic, in this scenario, is slightly too aggressive. I have logged a work item and this will be fixed in an upcoming release.

However, as a work-around, you can use the Metadata API to update the CRUD values on one or multiple permission sets. (keep ViewAll and ModifyAll set to False)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>TestPermissionSet</label>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>false</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>false</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>false</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Idea</object>
        <viewAllRecords>false</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    .
    .
    .
</PermissionSet>
```

Thank you again for posting and bringing this to our attention.

John

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Really appreciate it

Comment: Having same problem with v29.0, will try the metadata api as a workaround. Look forward to fix. Thanks

Comment: The issue should be resolved with the release of Summer '14 (see http://trust.salesforce.com/ for the release schedule).